# Keycloak: Rule-based groups

Tags: keycloak

I have configured Keycloak with user self-registration. The keycloak instance will hold users of multiple customers which I plan to put into groups (so each customer can have admins that can manage these users through fine-grained permissions).

To map users that are self-registering to appropriate groups (using their email address, e.g.) I'd like to put them in their default group upon registering. Is this possible using either configuration or implementing an SPI? Or are there other possibilities to achieve a similar behavior?